# How to do cross join between two H2OFrame in R?

Tags: r, h2o, cross-join

I want to  do cross join between two H2OFrames. Looking for work around **Strictly in H2OFrame**

```
col1.1 <- c('A', 'B', 'E', 'C', 'F', 'D')
dummy <- rep(1,6)

d1.hex <- as.h2o( cbind( col1.1, dummy ) )

col2.1 <- c('xx', 'yy', 'zz', 'ww')

dummy <- rep(1,4)

d2.hex <- as.h2o( cbind( col2.1, dummy ) )
```

If I use `all =TRUE` it throws Error : unimplemented

```
h2o.merge(d1.hex, d2.hex, all = TRUE)
```

If I use default, joining result is not cross join

```
h2o.merge(d1.hex, d2.hex )
```

> dummy col1.1 col2.1
>
> 1      A     xx
>
> 1      B     xx
>
> 1      E     xx
>
> 1      C     xx
>
> 1      F     xx
>
> 1      D     xx

I have tried changing data types of joining column to categorical or numeric but no success. Looking for your help in resolving the issue.

Thank you

Comment: so I'm not too familiar with h2o, but that is where you're running into the issue. The `merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)` is the correct way to cross join in R it seems.

Comment: Thank you @MattW. But I am looking for solution in H2OFrame. From reading file to making prediction, I am trying to use H2O and my data set is huge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frustrating answer is that you cannot, and there are already two bug reports for it:

https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-4516

https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-3699

The simplest workaround is to download all your data, and do it in the R client. But with big data that may not be possible. If you must do it in the H2O cluster you will need a loop:

1. Copy rows with first unique value in d1.hex into `tmp`
2. `tmp2 = h2o.merge(tmp, d2.hex, all.y = TRUE)`

Repeat for each unique value in d1.hex. Then, at the end, do a `h2o.rbind()` on all your `tmp2` tables.

Or, the classic open source solution: implement the unimplemented code yourself (or beg/pay h2o.ai to implement it).

Comment: Thank you @Darren. Appreciate your help and precise answer.